# Quickblox sigBytes error - authentication for chat

Tags: javascript, cordova, quickblox

Another quickblox question - I am getting the following error when trying to run my application:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sigBytes' of undefinedquickblox.js:10707 c.HMAC.i.extend.initquickblox.js:10703 i.Hasher.a.extend._createHmacHelperquickblox.js:101 signMessagequickblox.js:35 createSessionquickblox.js:867 QuickBlox.createSessionchat.html:122 (anonymous function)
```

This error prevents successful authentication of the user. The code being executed is below(insecure as hell - proof of concept only!):

```
var chatToUser = window.localStorage.getItem("chatToUser");
        var username = window.localStorage.getItem("user");
        var password = window.localStorage.getItem("pwd");
        var params = {login:username,password:password};

    console.log("PARAMS: ",params);

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var chatService = new QBChat(params);
    });

    // JavaScript SDK initialization
    QB.init(QBAPP.appID, QBAPP.authKey, QBAPP.authSecret);

    // QuickBlox session creation
    QB.createSession(params, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
                console.log("ERROR:", err.detail);
        } else {
                chatUser = {
                    id: result.user_id,
                    pass: params.password
                };

                connectChat();
        }
    });

    function connectChat() {
        chatService = new QBChat({
                onConnectFailed: onConnectFailed,
                onConnectSuccess: onConnectSuccess,
                onConnectClosed: onConnectClosed,
                onChatMessage: onChatMessage
        });

        console.log("Chat Service: ", chatService);
        console.log("Chat User: ", chatuser);
        // connect to QB chat service
        chatService.connect(chatUser);
    }

    /* Callbacks
    ------------------------------------------------------*/
    // Connection is failed
    function onConnectFailed() {
        alert("We're having some difficulty talking to the server. Please try again later, or get in touch if th eproblem persists.")
    }

    // Connection is success
    function onConnectSuccess() {
        //green dot - live - status
        alert("Connected.")
    }

    // Connection is closed
    function onConnectClosed() {}
```

What do i need to do differently in order to successfully log the user in for chat?

If it helps, I have previously generated a session for them based on their 'user' credentials (username/password). Is it possible to simply reuse this session instead of creating a fresh one?

Answer (score 0):

It just hit me! (adding a few console.logs helped...)

The app is looking for QBAPP.(etc) and the case/underscore formatting of those parameters did not line up after copying from an examples, hence the 'undefined'-s coming back and the sigbytes thingy falling over itself. So note to anyone else having this error - check your code carefully, for case and style before nagging the community with stupid questions!

I hope someone might learn from this.